# Умножение матриц различных типов

Tags: c++, opencv

К примеру у меня есть две матрицы: изображение и коэффициенты, на которые нужно домножить каждый пиксель изображения. Матрицы имеют одинаковую размерность, но разные типы: изображение `CV_8UC3`, а коэффициенты `CV_32FC1`. Функция `cv::multiply` здесь не подойдет из-за несоответствия типов. Можно конечно перемножать циклом, но я думаю должно быть решение получше этого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiply` можно использовать, только придётся подготовить матрицу коэффициентов:
 - преобразовать её `convertTo` с коэффициентом 255 (если диапазон был 0..1) из 32FC1 в 8UC1
-  потом размножить последнюю до 8UC3
-  и наконец применить multiply с параметром scale 1/255

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я понимаю тут имеется в виду применение битовой маски к изображению. Это не совсем умножение матриц. Нужно получить A[i,j]=A[i,j]*C[i,j].
Если так, то просто двойной цикл будет быстрым решением.

Comment: Простой двойной цикл я и так использую, но это решение вряд ли можно назвать оптимальным (хотя и самым простым)

Comment: Не очень понятно как это сделать быстрее, если нужно применить к каждому элементу матрицы. 

Оптимизировать можно, если есть дополнительная информация о структуре матрицы С, например разреженная.

Comment: вы не поняли, меня не интересует как сделать быстрее - а есть ли в opencv алгоритм, который осуществляет подобную операцию

Comment: Попробуйте какую-либо из map функиций, например convertMaps